# Firebase Real-time Database connection from Java -> JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to set up a Firebase Real-time Database connection from my Java backend to my JavaScript frontend, but the messages are not pushed to the client.

The backend Java code looks like this:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setServiceAccount(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/xxx.json"))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxx.firebaseio.com")
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference();

ref.child("users").setValue("aaa");
```

My javascript code on the frontend looks like this:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();

var myRef = firebase.database().ref("users");

myRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    alert(5);
});
```

Is there something wrong with this code or why are the messages are not pushed? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the alert fire at all? It should fire at least once when the front-end app starts. Also, you are writing the same value, so the value is not really changing. Have you tried writing a changing value?

Comment: @cartant: No its not fired at all. Why am I writing the same value? I was assuming I write the "users" object once on the BE and then catch it on the FE? Or is there something wrong in my thinking process?

Comment: The first problem to look into is the FE listener not firing. It should always fire at least once - even if the value does not exist, it should fire with a snapshot (`snapshot.exists()` will return `false`). Also, if the BE is overwriting the same value, I would not be surprised if the FE does not fire in response, as the value will not have *changed*.